# Creating a column in mysql to store uuid

Tags: 8, database

In Microsoft SQL we have UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type while creating table and when inserted it fills auto-generated string into that row. Is there any equivalent type in Drupal 8 or should I use some function in php to generate the string and while saving the row send the string as parameter(something like this $uuid = UUID::v4();). Currently I am creating the schema for that column as below. Is there a better way to implement this.

```
 'reference_unique_identifier' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 255,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => '',
  ),
```

**Note**: I am writing custom code to develop. I think I am not using entities. The above mentioned code is in a .install file which returns the schema.

Comment: For entities? Entities already get a UUID generated for them.

Comment: I am writing custom code to develop. I think I am not using entities. The above mentioned code is in a .install file which returns the schema and when the module is installed in website, corresponding tables are getting created in mysql.

Comment: Theres some competing questions here. If you are creating your own custom data structure, and not an entity, you are somewhat on your own. Two, Drupal 8 doesn't have much bearing on UUIDs as far as SQL goes in raw data structures. You can try looking at the Node module for examples, as it stores node entity entries with a UUID.

Comment: ohh ok. Thanks for the info, I will read into nodes and entities to get more clarity.

Comment: I am using uniqid() fucntion to generate the string in php and save it in mysql varchar column.  https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_uniqid.asp